# Explore and Display All PrimeNG Modules and Components Programmatically

Tags: angular, primeng

I need to display all primeng graphical compoents so the user can check and use dynamically

i am displaying them in a vertical list and user can select and drag and drop them in the screen so he can work with them latter

i need a way to retrieve the list

import * as AllModules from 'primeng

not returning anything

i need to return example

[table, autocomplete, input, tags ....]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Actually i need to display all primeng graphical component and end-user with drag and drop can select the libraries he would work with them. but i need a way to retrieve the list from primeng or any other webservice without hardcoding them